# Rsqlite leaves files locked after computer shutdown

Tags: r, sqlite

I have just started to dabble into the world of sqlite, primarily through R's interface package 'RSQLite'.

However, it seems like putting the computer to sleep while working on the sqlite data base left it locked, and trying to close the connection afterwards does not do anything. Furthermore, as the files is considered in use I'm not able to delete/overwrite the data base (or its -journal file, using Unlocker is not an option as I don't have those rights on the network drive the sqlite base is on).

Any offers on either manually how to force close the connection of the data base, or delete the -journal file successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to reset the network drive, which deleted the temporary -journal file and released the data base.

Comment: I'm not a guru with sqlite, but you might want to ensure the journal is not considered "hot", suggesting potential integrity issues with the original database. There is more documentation at [SQLite's locking/rollback](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#rollback) page.